# XAML listview items Background always rose color

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

When i get the listviewitem in focus the background color is always rose color.Couldnt understand why i get the color. Can i make the color disappear

```
<Grid x:Name="Playlist" Visibility="{Binding IsShow}" Width="960" >
        <Image x:Name="Bgimage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="540" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="960"/>
        <ListView x:Name="listview" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourCollection}"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" GotFocus="StackPanel_GotFocus" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" Margin="125,262,125,19" Foreground="{x:Null}" >

            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="200"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="200" Width="256">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Height="144" Width="256" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  Height="56" Width="256" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Image x:Name="image" Source="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="105" Margin="10,320,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105"/>
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain in detail, what we see on the picture and what you want to be different? Also, please explain a bit more what you do in the different parts of the XAML (`Bgimage`, `listview`, `image`, ...)

Comment: Bgimage(background image) and image(logo iamge) are just images that i display using image source reference and direct path reference respectively. I have thumbnail loaded from web (bottom series images). When i move the focus over these thumbnail the images/content get highlighted with a rose color background. I didnt set the color and not sure how to change it.

Comment: A typical [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)-job... inspect the control properties at runtime and get the relevant value sources for your unwanted color

Comment: Use the XAML Debug tools to debug the view. More info [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/08/07/live-visual-tree-in-visual-studio-3/)

Comment: Thanks the debug tool helped to track the issue. It was with the visibility (selectedbackground) color in style of Listviewitem needs to be changed. The default color is rose.